# Error react-hook-form TypeError: target.addObserver is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

when I create a react application(create-react-app) with `react-hook-form` and add `xmldom-ts` to it, it causes me the following error

> TypeError: target.addObserver is not a function
> MutationObserverImpl.observe

I attach Codesanbox where the problem is reproduced
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-perlman-bdkot?file=/src/App.js

If someone could give me directions on how to solve it, thank you very much

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error doesn't seem to have anything to do with react-hook-form, but rather with xmldom-ts that provides its own implementation of MutationObserver, which explodes when react-hook-form tries to use it. Apparently xmldom-ts is 3-year-old, there must be something more modern (and working) out there.